# pandas cut and apply: Unexpected behavior for series

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe I want to group w.r.t the freq column, bin the data and sum the count data for each bin.

Example data look like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"freq":[1,2,3], "count": [10,25,3]})
print(df)
   count  freq
0     10     1
1     25     2
2      3     3
```

To cut the data, I use

```
pd.cut(df.freq, bins=[0,1, np.infty])
```

with output

```
0      (0, 1]
1    (1, inf]
2    (1, inf]
Name: freq, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [(0, 1] < (1, inf]]
```

So everything works as expected. However, now I want to map the freq column of df on the corresponding bins. I thinkt, this could be achieved with apply.
However, using apply in the followig way

```
df.freq.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[0,1, np.infty]))
```

yields as TypeError

```
TypeError: putmask() argument 1 must be numpy.ndarray, not numpy.int64
```

However, when I enforce that df.freq is a DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(df.freq).apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[0,1, np.infty]))
```

the expected output according to a mapping onto the bins is returned

```
       freq
0    (0, 1]
1  (1, inf]
2  (1, inf]
```

So why is the Dataframe cast from Series-type necessary here? The TypeError hints that an expected array is an integer. However, checking the pandas.tile._bin_to_cut function I haven't seen where this behavior is comming from.

Any suggestions or is this intended?

btw. python 3.6 and pandas 0.19.2 are used

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of your "desired output" is.  You already have that data as the output of your `cut` call.  What are you trying to accomplish with the `apply`?

Comment: I want to map the freq columns to the bins and then group by the bins. I think I'm missing the mapping somewhere, but as you said and as jezrales shows, everything is already there

Comment: But why do you need to "map"?  Why not just group by the bin values you already have?

Comment: I thought I'd need map.I was just wrong there. My way of thinking was: Construct bins for the freq column; Map the values for the freq columns to the bins; group by bins. I thought a connection of bins and freq-values wasn't there. However, this is not the case. The cut functions returns this connection via index-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `apply` is not necessary, need only `groupby` by binned `Series` which return function [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
print (type(pd.cut(df.freq, bins=[0,1, np.infty])))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print (df.groupby(pd.cut(df.freq, bins=[0,1, np.infty]))['count'].sum().reset_index())
       freq  count
0    (0, 1]     10
1  (1, inf]     28
```

You can also assign output to new column:

```
df['freq'] = pd.cut(df.freq, bins=[0,1, np.infty])
print (df)

   count      freq
0     10    (0, 1]
1     25  (1, inf]
2      3  (1, inf]

print (df.groupby('freq')['count'].sum().reset_index())
       freq  count
0    (0, 1]     10
1  (1, inf]     28
```

---

```
df = df.assign(freq=pd.cut(df.freq, bins=[0,1, np.infty]))
print (df)
   count      freq
0     10    (0, 1]
1     25  (1, inf]
2      3  (1, inf]

print (df.groupby('freq')['count'].sum().reset_index())
       freq  count
0    (0, 1]     10
1  (1, inf]     28
```

Comment: In the first block of your answer, where and how do you ensure that group by actually groupy by the freq column? As we see above in my exampel cut returns a name. Is the column chosen with respect to this name? Afterwards, the rows of that columnd are mapped to the categorical levels of the cut-bins and we group. Is this what is happening here? Feels like a bit of magic

Comment: Standard way for using `groupby` is by `column name` like `df.groupby('freq')['count'].sum().reset_index()`. But if length of another series or numpy array is same as length of `DataFrame`, you can pass it to parameter `by`. Advantage is new column is not created, so solution is faster. But if different length it raise error.

Comment: I found it in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups)

Comment: Hmm,  this doesnt explain why we don't group by count. I think we rather use  _A dict or Series, providing a label -> group name mapping_ from your link. The Series has the label name = 'freq' and thus provides the requested mapping for the freq column

Comment: I think it does not groupby by `count` by cause in `groupby(HERE)` is only Series returned from `cut` function. and in `[]` but out of `groupby` are columns for aggregating - `groupby('')[HERE]`

Comment: ok, i just experimented with the names of the series object. What seems to happen is the following: The cut functions just returns a mapping from indexes to groups (and I think thats your point). Consequently, the groupby-function groups according to those index groups. Then we can choose any column for aggregation. Thanks for your efforts